# Is There Any Standard Rule of Buy-in Chips?

Tags: rules, cash-game

I just want to know if there is any standard rule of min and max buying chips? What I have noticed in Zynga poker is that the max buy-in chip is 200x of the big-blind. Meaning, for 5-10 blinds it is 10x200 = 2000, 2k-4k it is 800k is the buy-in.

Update:

This question I am mainly asking to set this rule for us playing with friends at house. Usually we play 5-10 bb and buy in 2k-3k. I think that huge for 5-10 blinds. Should we limit it to 1k only. How do you guys normally play in house. What do you suggest

Comment: Just to add, some people buy-in with one rack of chips. So, if a 5-10 game uses $10 chips, one rack would be $1K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules are *relative* to the online software, casino, or house you're playing in. There really are no rules per se; only common practices.

For example, many online sites now offer tables with variable minimum/maximum buyins ranging from 10-40bb, 40-100bb, or 100-250bb. Casino's from my experience will allow you to buy-in for whatever the largest stack at the table is at the time you take a seat. House rules...ask the host ;D!

Answer (score 1):

First of all why are you bothered about play money websites. As Toby said everything applies and there are no rules but however it is suited for your best interests in real-money games. How much can you afford to gamble with. Are you a `NIT` who gambles with only Aces or Kings or a loose-aggressive player.

So the buy-in depends on two factors:

- The amount you can afford to gamble with
- The type of poker player you are.

It also depends on the game - PLO, NL, Limit and the players at the table. If you smell fishes and its a PLO or NL, I would buy-in max and wait to set the trap.

There is one correction to TobyBooth: "Casino's from my experience will allow you to buy-in for whatever the largest stack at the table is at the time you take a seat"

It depends on the casino and usually in the states at the lowest level NL (1/2) they have predetermined max buy-in of 200. So, you can't buy-in for more unless your table is being broken and you are being (forced to) moved to another table and you want to play with whatever stack you are with. (Most of the Casino would accept this unless they have different rules)

Answer (score 1):

To add one more perspective; Casino's I've always found it a good rule to buy in (not tournament) for min 10x the BB, so you have a few rounds of play. For home games (again not tournament) we let our players buy in for whatever they want to risk and rebuy as long as they have $$ to spend!